# Почему Select из react-select неккоректно отображает options?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api

Всем привет. Делаю автодополнение адреса при помощи `googlemaps/js-api-loader` и `react-select`. Значения из инпута берутся верно, но Select не всегда отображает все варианты выбора. Не понимаю, с чем это связано.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего поиск идет по подстроке и запятые тоже учитываются...

Comment: @SwaD, точно, поиск! Забыл, что мы еще самим options ищем. Спасибо большое)